# Jacoco Sling Junit Integration-Test Execution

Tags: junit, integration-testing, aem, sling, jacoco

One of our test classes extends RemoteBaseTest but Jacoco ignores it completely.
How can I make Jacoco work with Sling Integration Testing?
For Unit Tests everything works as expected.
We are using Adobe CQ 5.6.1.
I see that this issue has been resolved: [sling-issue-tracker-2810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2810)
but unsure how to implement it - is it even included in the latest CQ-Version yet?
If not how do I manually add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `RemoteBaseTest` is but I assume you are running a JUnit "proxy" test which talks to the Sling JUnit server-side tests subsystem and causes the actual tests to run on your CQ server.

If that's correct, the actual test code doesn't run in the client JVM that's running RemoteBaseTest, it runs in the server JVM that's running CQ. So it's on the server JVM that you need to setup Jacoco to collect coverage data.

If you're running some tests on the client JVM (like common JUnit tests) and some on the server JVM via the Sling testing tools, Jacoco has functions to merge coverage data coming from different JVMs. We have this as a work in progress in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1803 , which is not fully integrated in Sling yet but should be adaptable to any version of CQ.